# How to check file exists in FTP c#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have in FTP server that will be created every 20 minutues and then deleted after certain time.I want to download  file once it created and before deleting.I did like

```
while (!File.Exists(reqFTP.RequestUri.ToString()))
                                    {
                                        if (DateTime.Now > timeout)
                                        {

                                        }
                                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                                    }
```

But no luck at all every time File.Exists return false.Here is full code

```
string uri = "ftp://" + dtr["FTP_SERVER"].ToString() + "/" + remoteftppath;
                                    Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);
                                    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
                                    {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    var timeout = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

                                    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                                    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + dtr["FTP_SERVER"].ToString() + "/" + remoteftppath));
                                    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(dtr["FTP_USER_ID"].ToString(), dtr["FTP_PASSWORD"].ToString());
                                    reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
                                    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                                    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                                    reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                                    reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
                                    while (!File.Exists(reqFTP.RequestUri.ToString()))
                                    {
                                        if (DateTime.Now > timeout)
                                        {

                                        }
                                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                                    }
                                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                                    responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

I dont know what is went wrong.It is not at all coming out from loop

Comment: I would have a look at the way you've arranged your logic - perhaps moving the loop would be of interest. In my opinion, you should handle file checking more like [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/348334/5697616)

Comment: there it is exception handling.For me my file will come every certain minutes and i have to download it .I don't want to go to exception

Comment: Don't then - I would still look into how you've arranged your logic in the code above.

Comment: Did you find any other method