# Check file existence on FTP server in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to check if some file exists on FTP server. I wrote code with `Test-Path` but it's not working. Then I wrote code to get FTP server file size, but it's not working either.

**My code**

```
function File-size()
{
   Param ([int]$size)
   if($size -gt 1TB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} TB ",$size /1TB)}
   elseif($size -gt 1GB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} GB ",$size/1GB)}
   elseif($size -gt 1MB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} MB ",$size/1MB)}
   elseif($size -gt 1KB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} KB ",$size/1KB)}
   elseif($size -gt 0) {[string]::Format("{0:0.00} B ",$size)}
   else                {""}
}

$urlDest = "ftp://ftpxyz.com/folder/ABCDEF.XML"
$sourcefilesize = Get-Content($urlDest)
$size = File-size($sourcefilesize.length)
Write-Host($size)
```

This code is not working.

**ERROR**

> Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'ftp' does not exist.At C:\documents\upload-file.ps1:67 char:19
>   + $sourcefilesize = Get-Item($urlDest)
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ftp:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Any idea how to solve this error? Is there any way I can check some exists into FTP server? Any clue regarding this will be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `Test-Path` nor `Get-Content` with FTP URL.

You have to use FTP client, like `WebRequest` ([`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest)).

Though it does not have any explicit method to check file existence (partly because FTP protocol itself does not have such functionality). You need to "abuse" a request like `GetFileSize` or `GetDateTimestamp`.

```
$url = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.txt"

$request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$request.Credentials =
    New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
$request.Method = [Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::GetFileSize

try
{
    $request.GetResponse() | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Exists"
}
catch
{
    $response = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response;
    if ($response.StatusCode -eq [Net.FtpStatusCode]::ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
    {
        Write-Host "Does not exist"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host ("Error: " + $_.Exception.Message)
    }
}
```

*The code is based on C# code from [How to check if file exists on FTP before FtpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/347897/850848)*.

---

If you want a more straightforward code, use some 3rd party FTP library.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell), you can use its [`Session.FileExists` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_fileexists):

```
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

if ($session.FileExists("/remote/path/file.txt"))
{
    Write-Host "Exists"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Does not exist"
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: thanks again :) ..absolutely right answer.learnt from you a lot.many many thanks to you once again :)